# How to screen double quotes in Google Docs re2 expressions?

Tags: regex, google-docs, re2

I'm trying to screen double quotes in regular expression on Google Sheets and there's no luck.
A1 cell text = `some "name"`
My formula

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"\"(.*)\"")
```

But Google Docs thinks that i'm using quotes for open /close argument. Please help.

Library that GoogleDocs using for regular expressions is re2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "[""]+(\w*)")

Answer (score 11):

You need to escape a doublequote `"` with another doublequote like this `""`.

Try using this,

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"""(.*)""")
```

Verified and this works well.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while here, but for anyone else looking for this answer - make sure you're using the right type of quote (Straight quotes vs Smart quotes). Just copy/paste the type of quote you're looking for